# from the yfinance library how can I read the ex-dividend date?

Tags: yfinance

This code should return the ex-dividend date:

`import yfinance as yf`

```
yf.Ticker('AGNC').info['exDividendDate']
```

but I get this as an output:
1661817600

I am wondering if there is a way to get the date from that number ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this number is obtained based on seconds. In order to get the real date, you can use `pd.to_datetime` to convert the seconds to calendar date.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime(1661817600, unit='s')
Out[6]: Timestamp('2022-08-30 00:00:00')
```

or you can use the built-in `datetime` package in Python.

```
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.fromtimestamp(1661817600))
2022-08-30 08:00:00
```